# Как сделать таймер обычно подсчета времени?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно сделать таймер(не обратного, а обычного)  подсчёта времени минут и секунд. Например нажимаешь на button, запускаеться подсчёт времени минут и секунд. Нажимаешь на другой button , сбрасывается на 0;

Есть ли какая библиотека для этого дела, или пример реализации такого таймера ?

Comment: StackOverflow  это не тот ресурс, где вам наготово напишут решение. Показывайте то, что вы уже сдедали, а участники помогут разобраться с тем, почему это не работает.
Код такого таймера можно уложить менее чем в 10 строк, поэтому вряд ли  здесь  необходимы какие то библиотеки. Начните изучение с функции `setInverval()`

Comment: О, у меня было такой где-то. Сейчас пришлю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var milisec = 0;
var sec = 0;
var min = 0;
var timer;
$("#start").click(startTimer);

function startTimer() {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    $("#milisec").text(milisec);
    milisec++;
    if (milisec == 100) {
      milisec = 0;
      sec++;
      $("#sec").text(sec);
    }
    if (sec == 60) {
      sec = 0;
      min++;
      $("#min").text(min);
    }
  }, 100);
}

$("#stop").click(function() {
  clearInterval(timer);
})
$("#cliear").click(function() {
  $("#milisec, #sec, #min ").text("0");
  milisec = 0;
  sec = 0;
  min = 0;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="timer">
<span id="min">0</span><i>:</i>
<span id="sec">0</span><i>:</i>
<span id="milisec">0</span>
<br>
</span>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<br>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<br>
<button id="cliear">Cliear</button>
```

Comment: setInterval не гарантирует что функция будет вызвана ровно через 100 мс.

Comment: @Arnial согласен(за исключением IE). можно попробовать рекурсивный setTimeout (), там есть четкий контроль задержки...

Comment: Я к тому, что скрипт может быть вызван не через 100мс, а через 200 или 300. К примеру из-за gc, repatin/reflow или другой долгой js функции. Лучше прибавлять к `milisec` разницу во времени между предыдущем и текущем вызовом, а не увеличивать всегда на 1.

Comment: @Arnial и с этим не могу не согласиться. Но мой пример абсолютно примитивен и создан лишь как один из возможных вариантов.

Answer (score 1):

Написан на css.

```js
window.createTimeCounter = function createTimeCounter(f, log) {
  var box = $('<div/>').addClass('timebox');
  ////////
  function num(n, t) {
      var s = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        s += i % 10 + '<br>';
      }
      s += '0';
      var a = 'time' + n + ' ' + t + 's linear infinite';
      if (log)
        console.log(n, t, a);
      return $('<div/>').html(s).addClass('timenumber')
        .css('animation', a);
    }
    ////////

  function hol(c, r, i) {
      if ('hmsc'.indexOf(c) == -1) return $('<b/>').html(c);
      var h = $('<div/>').addClass('timeholder');
      var a = {
        c: {
          def: [0.01, 10],
          11: [0.1, 10],
        },
        s: {
          def: [1, 10],
          20: [60, 6]
        },
        m: {
          def: [60, 10],
          20: [3600, 6]
        },
        h: {
          def: [3600, 10],
        }
      };
      var ac = a[c];
      var b = ac[10 * r + i];
      if (!b) {
        b = ac.def;
        b[2] = b[0];
        for (var j = 0; j < r - i; j++) b[2] *= b[1];
        b[0] = b[2];
      }
      if (log)
        console.log(10 * r + i, c, r, i, ac, ac.def, b);
      return h.append(
        num(b[1], b[0]));


    }
    ///////

  for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
    var c = f.charAt(i);
    var r = new RegExp(c, 'g');
    var reps = (f.match(r) || '').length;
    var ind = (f.substr(0, i).match(r) || '').length;;
    box.append(hol(c, reps, ind));
  }
  return box;
}
s = document.createElement('style');
s.innerHTML =
  '@keyframes time10 { 0% {top: 0px;} 100% {top: -200px;}}' +
  '@keyframes time6 { 0% {top: 0px;} 100% {top: -120px;}}' +
  '.timebox {display: inline-block;}' +
  '.timeholder { display: inline-block; width: 12px; height: 20px; overflow-y: hidden;}' +
  '.timebox b { display: inline-block; vertical-align: super; line-height: 20px;}' +
  '.timenumber { width: 10px; text-align: center; margin: auto; position: relative; line-height: 20px;}' +
  '.timebox * { border: 1px solid black;}';
document.head.appendChild(s);
createTimeCounter('hhh:mm:ss', 8).appendTo($('body'));
$('body').append('<br>');
createTimeCounter('ssss.cccccccc').appendTo($('body'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

самый простой вариант

```js
var secs, now, timer,
    mins = 0


function time(){
  secs = Math.floor((Date.now() - now)/1000)
  if(secs == 60 ){
    now = Date.now()
    mins++
  }
  if(secs < 10){
    secs = '0' + secs
  }
  timerid.innerHTML = mins + ':' + secs
}

start.onclick = function(){
  now = Date.now()
  mins = 0
  timer = setInterval(time)
}
```

```html
<button id="start">старт/сбросить</button>
<span id="timerid">0:00</span>
```